# Using grep to filter out Italian fiscal codes

Tags: regex, grep

I'm currently using this regex

```
/^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$/i
```

but for some reason grep gives me no results at all.

This is what I am executing:

```
grep -E -o "/^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$/i" filename.txt
```

Info on how an italian fiscal code is generated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_fiscal_code_card

Sample data:

```
fjksdhfdskjhfsdkjfhsjkfhsdMLLSNT82P65Z404Ukjfdshkjfsdhkjfdshfjdshmnbmnb
CF= "mrtmtt25d09f205z" (Region).
```

Expected output:

```
MLLSNT82P65Z404U    
mrtmtt25d09f205z
```

Comment: How about some sample data with the expected output. Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: I've updated my question @JamesBrown.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, already updated the question!

Comment: You need to remove both `^` and `$` and also use the `g` flag in addition to `i`.

Comment: Show your actual code where you are using the regex. Note that `grep` does not accept `/.../` notation, `/` chars are treated as normal chars and to make it work with a PCRE `-P` option, you need to revamp it to `(?i)^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed /[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]/i/g like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -io "[A-Z]\{6\}[0-9]\{2\}[A-Z][0-9]\{2\}[A-Z][0-9]\{3\}[A-Z]" file
MLLSNT82P65Z404U
mrtmtt25d09f205z
```

or

```
$ grep -Eio "[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{3}[A-Z]" file
```

or

```
$ grep -Pio "[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]" file
```

`man grep`:

```
-i, --ignore-case
       Ignore case distinctions in  both  the  PATTERN  and  the  input
       files.
-o, --only-matching
       Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
       with each such part on a separate output line.
-E, --extended-regexp
       Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression 
-P, --perl-regexp
       Interpret the pattern as a  Perl-compatible  regular  expression
       (PCRE).   This  is  highly  experimental and grep -P may warn of
       unimplemented features.
```